# ANTLR4 4.11.1 demo crashes with Unknown error -1

Tags: c++, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to use ANTLR4 in a C++ project on Linux, so I cloned the [git repo](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4), checked it out to the v4.11.1 tag, downloaded the matching `antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar` tool from the [website](https://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar) and managed to build the C++ runtime with the demo included:

```
cd runtime/Cpp
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DANTLR_JAR_LOCATION=$HOME/packages/antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar -DWITH_DEMO=True 
make -j
```

But when trying to run `antlr4-demo`, it crashes with an unknown error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Unknown error -1
Aborted (core dumped)
```

From what I could see, the error is coming from `tokens.fill();`.

Is this a bug or am I missing some configuration or build step?

EDIT: I haven't noticed that there is a 4.12.0 branch (not starting with v), so I downloaded the corresponding jar and recompiled the runtime, but the error still persists.

Comment: It might be easier for you if you apply [trgen](https://github.com/kaby76/Domemtech.Trash/tree/main/src/trgen) to a grammar in [grammars-v4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4). E.g., the [calculator grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/calculator) via `trgen -t Cpp --antlr-tool-path ..../antlr4-4.12.0-complete.jar`. (You should use 4.12.0, not 4.11.1 at this point.) C++ can be tricky because the target requires way too much in setting up the environment.

Comment: Version 4.12.0 still produces the same error. Haven't tried trgen through.

Comment: That question would be better of as a bug ticket. Did you check their issues at GitHub's?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt no similar issue on GH. The issue submission form states to seek help here first.

Comment: Please create an issue in https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues. I've always had trouble with the demo, especially Windows Cygwin. Took me quite a while to get the templates working on the different OSes for Cpp.

Comment: +1 on this issue, did you guys find how to fix this issue? I am facing the same issue with 13.1.0 at this moment